# How to find the format of Date ios sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a date in format : `Jun 22, 2015, 01.30PM IST`

I am unable to convert it in NSDate.

I am using this format to convert it: `MMM dd, yyyy, hh.mma zzzz` 
I am getting null when I use NSLog.

Also I want to find the number of minutes between current time and this time. How can I solve these two issues.

```
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dateValue objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];    
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"MMM dd, yyyy, hh.mma zzzz";

  NSLog(@"%@", [formatter dateFromString:[dateValue objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]);
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. You are showing 3 different formats. Which one are you really trying to use?

Comment: see i removed extra part

Comment: Your question still shows two different formats. One in the question and one in the code.

Comment: @rmaddy see now its clear

Comment: You have the comma in format in the incorrect place.  It that a typo in your question?

Comment: And you need `yyyy`, not `YYYY` for the year.

Answer (score 1):

Your format is actually `MMM d, yyyy, h.ma zzzz`
I use [this cheatsheet](https://gist.github.com/romaonthego/5138532) for NSDateFormatter.

For the second part:

```
NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2];
double numberOfMinutes = distanceBetweenDates / 60;
```

Comment: will you assist me for second part

Comment: Are you sure of the string you are passing in the date formatter ? Can you log it to the console to make sure ? Also, double check the format I gave you. Did you paste it right ?

Comment: How can i convert the current date into this format

Comment: Can you do a  NSLog(@"%@",[dateValue objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]); and tell us what's the output ?

Comment: Aug 10, 2015, 05.04PM IST this the value I get..see I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

the procedure would be something like this:

## step 1., parsing the date

```
NSString *_stringDate = @"Jun 22, 2015, 01.30PM IST";
NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
_dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MMM dd, yyyy, hh.mma z";
NSDate *_parsedDate = [_dateFormatter dateFromString:[_stringDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"IST" withString:@"+0530"]];
```

---

*NOTE: the `"IST"` might not be a timezone which the parser can interpret so you may need to replace it in some certain cases by its equivalent value in hours, which is `"+0530"`.*

---

## step 2., calculating the difference

```
NSCalendar *_calendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSCalendarUnit _unit = NSCalendarUnitMinute;
NSDateComponents *_componenets = [_calendar components:_unit fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:_parsedDate options:0];

NSInteger _differenceInMinutes = _componenets.minute;
```

---

*NOTE: the difference can be either zero, negative or positive value as well.*

Comment: It always gives me negative value like -33014 minutes..I tried after changing dates but result was the same.. @holex

Comment: yes, because the date is in _past_. if it had been in _future_ the return value would have been positive; that is what I mentions exactly about the difference; it can be either positive or negative value.

Comment: Do not use `YYYY` for the year. Use `yyyy`.

Comment: @rmaddy, actually, you are right. I have updated that.